# Unble to create synapse workspace sql bool using bicep getting error (Code: CreateSqlComputeOrchestrationError;OperationInterrupted)

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-bicep

Attempting to create a synapse workspace and sql pool using bicep. Getting the error message below.

`SQL Datawarehouse 'sql_pool_1' creation for workspace synapseyjdzc2vokh in subscription xxxxx did not succeed The operation on the resource could not be completed because it was interrupted by another operation on the same resource. (Code: CreateSqlComputeOrchestrationError;OperationInterrupted)`

I have tried several things and made a number of changes, without little information on the error I am finding it difficult to ascertain the root cause of the error.

Main.bicep file.

```
//scope
targetScope = 'resourceGroup'
param utcValue string = utcNow()
var randomstring = toLower(replace(uniqueString(subscription().id, resourceGroup().id, utcValue), '-', ''))
param ipaddress string
var synapseName = 'synapse${randomstring}'
param sqlAdministratorLogin string
@secure()
param sqlAdministratorLoginPassword string
var blobName = 'storage${randomstring}'
param storageAccountType string
param sqlpoolName string
param bigDataPoolName string
param nodeSize string
param sparkPoolMinNodeCount int
param sparkPoolMaxNodeCount int
param defaultDataLakeStorageFilesystemName string
param collation string
param userObjectId string
param dataLakeUrlFormat string
param location string

//Storage account for deployment scripts
module synapsedeploy 'synapse-workspace.bicep' = {
  name: 'synapsed'
  params: {
    synapseName: synapseName
    location: location
    sqlAdministratorLogin: sqlAdministratorLogin
    sqlAdministratorLoginPassword: sqlAdministratorLoginPassword
    blobName: blobName
    storageAccountType: storageAccountType
    sqlpoolName: sqlpoolName
    bigDataPoolName: bigDataPoolName
    nodeSize: nodeSize
    sparkPoolMinNodeCount: sparkPoolMinNodeCount
    sparkPoolMaxNodeCount: sparkPoolMaxNodeCount
    defaultDataLakeStorageFilesystemName: defaultDataLakeStorageFilesystemName
    collation: collation
    startIpaddress: ipaddress
    endIpAddress: ipaddress
    userObjectId: userObjectId
    dataLakeUrlFormat: dataLakeUrlFormat
  }
}

output resourceSuffix string = randomstring
```

synapse-workspace.bicep

```
param synapseName string
param location string
param sqlAdministratorLogin string
@secure()
param sqlAdministratorLoginPassword string
param blobName string
param storageAccountType string
param sqlpoolName string
param bigDataPoolName string
param nodeSize string
param sparkPoolMinNodeCount int
param sparkPoolMaxNodeCount int
param defaultDataLakeStorageFilesystemName string
param collation string
param startIpaddress string
param endIpAddress string
param userObjectId string
param dataLakeUrlFormat string


var storageBlobDataContributorRoleID = 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe'
var storageRoleUniqueId = guid(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', synapseName), blobName)
var storageRoleUserUniqueId = guid(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', synapseName), userObjectId)
resource datalakegen2 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-09-01' = {
  name: blobName
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  location: location
  properties:{
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    isHnsEnabled: true
  }
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountType
  }
}

resource blob 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-09-01' = {
  name:  '${datalakegen2.name}/default'
}

resource containera 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2021-09-01' = {
  name: '${datalakegen2.name}/default/${defaultDataLakeStorageFilesystemName}'
  properties: {
    publicAccess: 'None'
  }
  dependsOn:[
    blob
  ]
} 

resource synapse 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces@2021-06-01' = {
  name: synapseName
  location: location
  properties: {
    sqlAdministratorLogin: sqlAdministratorLogin
    sqlAdministratorLoginPassword: sqlAdministratorLoginPassword
    defaultDataLakeStorage:{
      accountUrl: format(dataLakeUrlFormat, datalakegen2.name)
      filesystem: defaultDataLakeStorageFilesystemName
    }
  }
  identity:{
    type:'SystemAssigned'
  }
}

resource synapseroleassing 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-10-01-preview' = {
  name: storageRoleUniqueId
  scope: datalakegen2
  properties:{
    principalId: synapse.identity.principalId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
    roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', storageBlobDataContributorRoleID)
  }
}

resource userroleassing 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-10-01-preview' = {
  name: storageRoleUserUniqueId
  scope: datalakegen2
  properties:{
    principalId: userObjectId
    principalType: 'User'
    roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', storageBlobDataContributorRoleID)
  }
}

resource manageid4Pipeline 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/managedIdentitySqlControlSettings@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'default'
  properties: {
    grantSqlControlToManagedIdentity: {
      desiredState:'Enabled'
    }
  }
  parent:synapse
}

resource sqlpool 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/sqlPools@2021-06-01' = {
  name: sqlpoolName
  location: location
  parent: synapse
  sku:{
    name: 'DW100c'
  }
  properties:{
    collation: collation
    createMode: 'Default'
  }
}

resource sparkpool 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/bigDataPools@2021-06-01' = {
  name: bigDataPoolName
  location: location
  parent: synapse
  properties:{
    nodeSize: nodeSize
    nodeSizeFamily: 'MemoryOptimized'
    autoScale:{
      enabled: true
      minNodeCount: sparkPoolMinNodeCount
      maxNodeCount: sparkPoolMaxNodeCount
    }
    autoPause:{
      enabled: true
      delayInMinutes: 15
    }
    sparkVersion: '3.2'
  }
}

// resource allowazure4synapse 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/firewallRules@2021-06-01' = {
//   name: 'AllowAllWindowsAzureIps'
//   properties: {
//     endIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
//     startIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
//   }
//   parent: synapse
// }

// resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/firewallRules@2021-06-01' = {
//   name: 'AllowAccessPoint'
//   properties: {
//     endIpAddress: endIpAddress
//     startIpAddress: startIpaddress
//   }
//   parent: synapse
// }
```

parameter file.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {  

        "ipaddress": {
            "value": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        },
        "sqlAdministratorLogin": {
          "value" : "adminuser"
        },
        "sqlAdministratorLoginPassword": {
          "value": "dffgf5^645*DGGD2"
        },
        "storageAccountType":{
          "value": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "sqlpoolName":{
          "value": "sql_pool_1"
        },
        "bigDataPoolName": {
          "value": "etlexecuter"
        },
        "nodeSize":{
          "value": "Small"
        },
        "sparkPoolMinNodeCount":{
            "value": 3
        },
        "sparkPoolMaxNodeCount":{
          "value": 3
        },
        "defaultDataLakeStorageFilesystemName":{
          "value": "dl2"
        },
        "collation":{
          "value": "SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS"
        },
        "userObjectId":{
          "value": "xxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "dataLakeUrlFormat":{
          "value": "https://{0}.dfs.core.windows.net"
        }
    }
}
```

deployment

```
az deployment group create --resource-group "my-rg" --template-file "D:\bicep\main.bicep" --parameters "D:\bicep\parameters.json" --name synapse_deployment
```

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Operation interrupted error might cause if there is a parallel deployment going on in your environment. @learner

Comment: There is no parallel deployment happening at thesame time, does it work for you ?

Comment: The above code worked for me in my environment as shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/NtmSNng.png). @learner

Comment: try deploy sub resource sequentially => adding explict depends on. for example create the sqlPools then make the bigDataPools depdenson sqlPools.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I upgraded my bicep version and then tried it again a few days later and it worked. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a temporary issue which might cause due to below reasons.*

Verify if there are any ongoing deployments either through the Azure Portal or CLI, as simultaneous deployments by multiple users in the same environment can cause this issue.

Consider deploying your resources in a different region than the current one. I suggest deploying to the `WestUS2` region as it typically has fewer limits on SQL pool resources.

Sometimes, redeploying the bicep code will work in this kind of scenarios.

Check bicep and CLI version and upgrade it with `az bicep upgrade` if it is an outdated version.

Your code looks good to me for your requirement. I tried the same code in my environment as you and was able to deploy it as shown below.

```bash
param synapseName string
param location string
param sqlAdministratorLogin string
@secure()
param sqlAdministratorLoginPassword string
param blobName string
param storageAccountType string
param sqlpoolName string
param bigDataPoolName string
param nodeSize string
param sparkPoolMinNodeCount int
param sparkPoolMaxNodeCount int
param defaultDataLakeStorageFilesystemName string
param collation string
param userObjectId string
param dataLakeUrlFormat string


var storageBlobDataContributorRoleID = 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe'
var storageRoleUniqueId = guid(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', synapseName), blobName)
var storageRoleUserUniqueId = guid(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', synapseName), userObjectId)
resource datalakegen2 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-09-01' = {
  name: blobName
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  location: location
  properties:{
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    isHnsEnabled: true
  }
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountType
  }
}

resource blob 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-09-01' = {
  name:  '${datalakegen2.name}/default'
}

resource containera 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2021-09-01' = {
  name: '${datalakegen2.name}/default/${defaultDataLakeStorageFilesystemName}'
  properties: {
    publicAccess: 'None'
  }
  dependsOn:[
    blob
  ]
} 

resource synapse 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces@2021-06-01-preview' = {
  name: synapseName
  location: location
  properties: {
    sqlAdministratorLogin: sqlAdministratorLogin
    sqlAdministratorLoginPassword: sqlAdministratorLoginPassword
    defaultDataLakeStorage:{
      accountUrl: format(dataLakeUrlFormat, datalakegen2.name)
      filesystem: defaultDataLakeStorageFilesystemName
    }
  }
  identity:{
    type:'SystemAssigned'
  }
}

resource synapseroleassing 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-10-01-preview' = {
  name: storageRoleUniqueId
  scope: datalakegen2
  properties:{
    principalId: synapse.identity.principalId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
    roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', storageBlobDataContributorRoleID)
  }
}

resource userroleassing 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-10-01-preview' = {
  name: storageRoleUserUniqueId
  scope: datalakegen2
  properties:{
    principalId: userObjectId
    principalType: 'User'
    roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', storageBlobDataContributorRoleID)
  }
}

resource manageid4Pipeline 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/managedIdentitySqlControlSettings@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'default'
  properties: {
    grantSqlControlToManagedIdentity: {
      desiredState:'Enabled'
    }
  }
  parent:synapse
}

resource sqlpool 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/sqlPools@2021-06-01' = {
  name: sqlpoolName
  location: location
  parent: synapse
  sku:{
    name: 'DW100c'
  }
  properties:{
    collation: collation
    createMode: 'Default'
  }
}

resource sparkpool 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/bigDataPools@2021-06-01' = {
  name: bigDataPoolName
  location: location
  parent: synapse
  properties:{
    nodeSize: nodeSize
    nodeSizeFamily: 'MemoryOptimized'
    autoScale:{
      enabled: true
      minNodeCount: sparkPoolMinNodeCount
      maxNodeCount: sparkPoolMaxNodeCount
    }
    autoPause:{
      enabled: true
      delayInMinutes: 15
    }
    sparkVersion: '3.2'
  }
}
```

```bash
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "synapseName": {
      "value": "mynewsynap"
    },
    "location": {
      "value": "westus2"
    },
    "sqlAdministratorLogin": {
      "value": "roots"
    },
    "sqlAdministratorLoginPassword": {
      "value": "Jaanu@041297"
    },
    "blobName": {
      "value": "newblobjah"
    },
    "storageAccountType": {
      "value": "Standard_LRS"
    },
    "sqlpoolName": {
      "value": "mypoolj"
    },
    "bigDataPoolName": {
      "value": "bigpoolj"
    },
    "nodeSize": {
      "value": "Small"
    },
    "sparkPoolMinNodeCount": {
      "value": 3
    },
    "sparkPoolMaxNodeCount": {
      "value": 10
    },
    "defaultDataLakeStorageFilesystemName": {
      "value": "dl2"
    },
    "collation": {
      "value": "SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS"
    },
    "userObjectId": {
      "value": "b5xxxx18"
    },
    "dataLakeUrlFormat": {
      "value": "https://{0}.dfs.core.windows.net"
    }
  }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

[image]